# When in lifecycle does activity transition happen?

Tags: android, surfaceview, transition, progressdialog

One of my activities contains a SurfaceView which takes a while to load (some bitmaps, etc).
I use overridePendingTransition in all my activities' onPause() to play a custom fade transition.

So when I switch from another activity back to the SurfaceView, there is some delay involved while things are loaded. I see that the transition only starts after the destination activity is ready (ie after its onResume, onSurfaceCreated, etc are called).

1) Does anyone know when exactly in the lifecycle does the transition actually play?

2) What would be the best way to show a ProgressDialog in the first activity until the transition happens? At the moment the user presses the button to switch, and then nothing happens while the new activity loads, and only after it loads does the transition play.

I've tried putting progressDialog.show() in the first activity's onPause(), but then for some reason the second activity's SurfaceView shows up blank for the first few seconds after opening.

Comment: Have you tried creating showing the dialog as the first step in `onResume()` of the new activity instead? You don't want to create a dialog with the old activity's context just as you're finishing it.

Comment: Thanks, tried it, but the old activity is still on the screen when onResume() is called on the new activity. It only transitions to the new activity after onRestart() and onResume() of the new activity has already been called.

Comment: If there is a "delay while things are loading", you might want to offload that onto another thread. This way the UI for the Activity will show up sooner, along with the dialog.

Comment: Thanks, I already have all my canvas animation stuff on a separate thread, but maybe there's something I missed, I'll go through it again.

Comment: So I narrowed down the problem: Android calls onResume() immediately, but it takes a while before it calls onWindowFocusChanged(). The activity isn't guaranteed to be visible when onResume() is called, at least from Android 4.1 and up. So it isn't my code causing the delay. There is a delay between onResume and when Android actually shows the activity (I assume because the SurfaceView takes a while to render or something), and it's during that delay where I need to show something.

Comment: I've created a separate question for this new issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906623/android-delay-between-onresume-and-onwindowfocuschanged

Comment: @plsch Hi! Have you been able to find solution to your problem?